# Swipebox - Open Images Individually instead of Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, gallery, lightbox

I'm in the process of finding a mobile alternative to Colorbox. [Swipebox](http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/) seemed like a great alternative, but unlike colorbox it doesn't seem to allow every individual image open but combined all of them into a gallery. The conventional way of adding swipebox is as so:

`$('.class').swipebox();`

which adds everything with that class into a swipebox gallery. Is there a way to instead open each item of a certain class individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just need to separate your images into "galleries", which may seem counter intuitive as you don't want galleries...

[Check the advanced docs for gallery](http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/#rel):

> You can add a rel attribute to your links to separate your galleries.

Like I said it's counter intuitive, but the feature that's designed to group images together into galleries can be used to separate them. Basically you're setting up galleries of one by adding a different rel attribute to each one.

**[Working Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgp1bcvL/1/)**

```js
$('.swipebox').swipebox();
```

```css
img {
  width: 500px;/* example only */
}
```

```html
<link href="http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/src/css/swipebox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/src/js/jquery.swipebox.js"></script>

<a href="http://pluggedinwebdesign.com/images/RopesLittlePlanet.jpg" class="swipebox" title="My Caption" rel="gallery-1">
  <img src="http://pluggedinwebdesign.com/images/RopesLittlePlanet.jpg" alt="image" />
</a>

<a href="http://pluggedinwebdesign.com/images/CanopyGround.jpg" class="swipebox" title="My Caption" rel="gallery-2">
  <img src="http://pluggedinwebdesign.com/images/CanopyGround.jpg" alt="image" />
</a>
```

If adding a rel attribute to every swipebox looks tedious, you can add the rel attribute with a little script:

```js
$('.swipebox').swipebox();

var X = 0; // set a global var 
$('.swipebox').each(function() { //for each swipebox
  X += 1; //increment the global var by 1
  $(this).attr('rel', 'gallery-' + X); // set the rel attribute to gallery- plus the value of X
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 500px;/* example only */
}
```

```html
<link href="http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/src/css/swipebox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/src/js/jquery.swipebox.js"></script>

<a href="http://pluggedinwebdesign.com/images/RopesLittlePlanet.jpg" class="swipebox" title="My Caption">
  <img src="http://pluggedinwebdesign.com/images/RopesLittlePlanet.jpg" alt="image" />
</a>

<a href="http://pluggedinwebdesign.com/images/CanopyGround.jpg" class="swipebox" title="My Caption">
  <img src="http://pluggedinwebdesign.com/images/CanopyGround.jpg" alt="image" />
</a>
```

Comment: While this is still correct, the rel attribute won't validate for the HTML5 specifications so warning future readers.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I thought about that while writing the answer, I know fancybox and a few other lightbox plugins started using a `data- ` attribute so that the html would pass validation.

Comment: It may be an oversight of swipebox so I'll bring it up on their github page.

Comment: FYI, you can use 'data-rel' in place of 'rel' with SwipeBox. Works fine!

Answer (score 0):

My simple solution :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
;( function( $ ) {
  $( '.swipebox' ).swipebox();
  $( '.swipebox2' ).swipebox();
} )( jQuery );
</script>
```

---

```
<a href="big/1-1.jpg" class="swipebox"><img src="small/1-1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="big/1-2.jpg" class="swipebox"><img src="small/1-2.jpg" /></a>

<a href="big/2-1.jpg" class="swipebox2"><img src="small/2-1.jpg" /></a>
<a href="big/2-2.jpg" class="swipebox2"><img src="small/2-2.jpg" /></a>
```